# Swift 4.0 - iOS 13 - Textfield doesn't open keyboard on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I have taken textfield in tableview cell and different types of textfield are there like with picker input, with text input etc in different cells.

Initially when I entered screen and try to enter into each textfield everything works fine but once I scroll through screen up and down something goes wrong and some textfields don't open the keyboard on tap..

I have integrated latest IQKeyboardManager library and this issue is only in iOS13. In above OS, its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

// Inside this method, set delegate of textField IBOutlet created in UITableViewCell class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    // enter code here

       cell.nameTextField.delegate = self;

    // enter code here

}
```